# How to rotate darkmode/lightmode button more than once using Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, transform, rotatetransform

I'm trying to set up a div with an image background as the selector for darkmode/daymode.  The only problem seems to be how to rotate the image 180degree on click so that it displays the daysky when darkmode is selected and rotate it 180degrees to the nightsky when lightmode is selected.

My HTML:
`<div id="selector" class="selector"></div>`

the CSS (bg image is a circle.  The sun and sunrays to the left.  To the right the moon and stars.  :

```
height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/32/25/day-and-night-icon-isolated-on-background-vector-21083225.jpg');
  background-size: 120%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center, center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* rotate 90deg sets the background image with the night sky on top part of the image*/
 transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  cursor: pointer;
```

The 90deg rotation puts the image with the darksky on top (ergo: ready for darkmode selection).

JS:

```
const elem = document.getElementById('selector');
elem.addEventListener('click', spin);
function spin() {
  elem.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
}
```

On the first click of the image it rotates the div 180deg, but based on its original position not on the 90deg rotation done with the CSS.  I can work around that.  The problem is any subsequent clicking of the image will no longer rotate it because the transform property for that element is already `rotate(180deg);`

Comment: Store the angle in a variable in the outer scope, and increase it by 180 every time the button is clicked, then create the value for transform using the variable.

Answer (score 0):

For the first rotation, rotate by 90 degrees. Then each subsequent one rotate 180 degrees from the previous click, using a variable in the outer scope.

By using
`deg = (deg + 180) % 360`
you keep the variable alternating between 90 and 270. The 270 degree rotation is the same as your -90 degree initial rotation.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('selector');
elem.addEventListener('click', spin);
var deg = 90
function spin() {
  elem.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
  deg = (deg + 180) % 360
}
```

```css
.selector {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/32/25/day-and-night-icon-isolated-on-background-vector-21083225.jpg');
  background-size: 120%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center, center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* rotate 90deg sets the background image with the night sky on top part of the image*/
 transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="selector" class="selector" style='background-image: url("https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/32/25/day-and-night-icon-isolated-on-background-vector-21083225.jpg")'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is perfect.